# How to calculate a DXF's used area in Python 3 with ezdxf or dxfgrabber?

Tags: python-3.x, dxf

I would like to calculate the minimum size of an rectangle that contains all elements of an DXF file, but apparently neither ezdxf or dxfgrabber have a function to do that.

Is iterating through all entities and calculating the points the only way to do it? If the drawing used only lines and boxes that would be easy, but with splines, arcs and circles the process become tiring.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the context of my answer does not relate to the **libraries** you refer. But if you look [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-70B3140A-14F1-4F54-AF5F-8DEDB444C3BA-htm.html) it mentions:

> **[Extmin](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-F37FCEB8-FD86-4E8A-9DB3-A5163B2C0AE0-htm.html)** and **[Extmax](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-B3926CFA-DE74-4661-A9A5-2738A1FD937B-htm.html)** - Returns the extents of Model space.
>
> **Pextmin** and **Pextmax** - Returns the extents of the current Paper space layout.

Are you able to access these variables using your libraries? If not, then you most likely have to do it the manual way.

Comment: Apparently Fusion360 doesn't put those variables inside their DXF files.

Comment: Oh dear. There are other libraries like Teigha.DWG that have geometry support for extents. Splines would be a nightmare because of their complexity.

Comment: I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/python-ezdxf/CSGeTQnyBe4 I think you need to use a different methodology.